# In Android Getting os.network on main thread exception

Tags: android, http, httpclient

In andriod I am accessing my local address (Ex:'http:/192.168.173.1/something'). I want  to read the content,but it is showing the exception os.Network on main thread Exception.I want to work on my website only, but this is the problem
Can anybody solve my problem and help me...

Comment: This exception only comes in my emulator, but in my phone I am not getting any exception.....

Comment: That's most likely because your phone is running Android 2.3 or older whereas the emulator is running 4.0 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a thread in order to make network requests. You cant make any http request in android on main UI thread. try using asyntask

Comment: This exception only comes in my emulator, but in my phone I am not getting any exception

Comment: This is because this was added in later version of Android. You're phones would have different Android version than emulator

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask and perform your operation on doInBackground Method